# Why would Laura have an adamantium skeleton?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

This pertains to the new movie Logan, spoiler alert.

Is there an explained reason why Laura had an adamantium skeleton? If their goal was to make mutant super soldiers from a young age, I would think such a skeleton would hinder growth and disfigure her, thus making her useless as a super soldier. Why wouldn't they wait until she was fully grown?

Comment: I know there have been lots of debates about spoilers here, but saying 'spoiler alert' in the first sentence when you've already shown the spoiler in the title seems a bit pointless.  And yes, there are ways of writing a title to this that would give enough information without including the spoiler.

Answer (score 5):

She has more than just adamantium claws. The file we see on X-23-23 (Laura is the 23rd clone of the 23rd Weapon X program) shows multiple locations for adamantium injections. There is no proof that she had her claws removed for adamantium coating **in the film universe**. Unlike Wolverine though, it did not indicate she underwent complete adamantium bonding. Likely just adamantium lacing, like comic Bullseye or Sabertooth do at some points.

**When official releases of the movie come out, a high resolution screenshot will prove this.**

This is just one of the differences that the project takes. In the comics, Laura is not a child or preteen, she is a teenager. She is one of multiple female clones of Wolverine while the movie shows only one clone of multiple different mutants. She is not part of the Old Man Logan universe. Etc.

Comment: X-23-23? That's some crazy Illuminati numbering right there.

Comment: @jdoe the black kid iirc was X-23-24. It's just a sequential number.

Comment: That's what *they* want you to think.

Answer (score 4):

In the film universe, X-23 does NOT have a full adamantium-coated skeleton like Logan does (which is also the case in the comics). Instead, her organic bone claws were surgically removed, coated with adamantium, then re-inserted. One of the promotional videos for the film takes the form of a "leaked" video that shows what's being done to her by the project, and several scenes show the claws being surgically inserted:

[image]

If you look just below her feet in that screenshot, you can see four of the six claws still laying on the table. They're already coated with adamantium at this point, so they're going back in. Since there is blood on her feet & legs and only four claws left, they presumably already put in the two foot claws and are now preparing the arms.

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer

She does not have a full skeleton, just her claws

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-23#Powers_and_abilities)

> Unlike Wolverine, however, X-23 has only two claws per hand which are her primary weapons of offence. She also possesses a single, retractable claw housed within each foot which she tends to use for defense. These claws are actually made of bone and were forcefully extracted by Zander Rice, sharpened, coated with adamantium, and reinserted into her body. Also unlike Wolverine, X-23 escaped before the procedure to fuse her entire skeleton with adamantium could be performed.

Comment: The movie does not 100% connect to the comic origin.

Comment: @cde It is still perfectly acceptable to seek answers in the source material when the movies do not provide them. Otherwise we'd be asking absurd questions like "Why do all these characters and stories resemble the comics?"

Comment: @jdoe except when the movie and source material differ or contradict. As they do here.

Comment: i really hope for the kid that this is true, otherwise i wonder how the hell she'd grow... prettu sure adamantium skeletons don't grow

Comment: @brian in the comics the adamantium bonds at a biological level and wolverines healing actor can create and repair it. So she can still grow. Maybe. It's not consistent.

Comment: @cde - you're right about that. In the comics, Wolverine doesn't have "true" adamantium in his body. His healing factor combined the adamantium with the bones on a cellular/molecular level and actually formed a new compound. That doesn't explain how the adamantium can be removed by Magneto or re-inserted by first Genesis then Apocalypse, but hey... comics.